# How can I draw two functions with TikZ picture

Tags: tikz-pgf

I want to draw the picture below but I do not know how to.

[image]

This is my code although it is not running:

```
‎‎\begin{tikzpicture}‎[>=stealth,scale=10]‎
\draw[color=gray!30,very thin](-0.1,-0.004)‎
gri‎d[ystep=0.01,xstep=0.1](1.02,0.042);‎
\draw[->](-0.1,0)--(1.02,0);‎
\draw[->](0,-0.004)--(0,0.042);‎‎‎
\draw[thick,blue,domain=0:1.02,samples=200] plot(\x,{(\x)/(70*(2-\x*\x))}) node[below‎] {‎$y=‎\frac{q}{70(2-‎q^2)}‎‎‎$‎};;‎‎‎‎
\draw[thick,red,domain=0:1,samples=200] plot(\x,{(1+sqrt(1-\x*\x))/(70)}) node[above] {‎$y=‎\frac{1}{70}(1+\sqrt{1-‎q^2})‎‎‎$‎};;‎‎‎
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Does anyone know how I can change my code to draw this please?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 3):

**Edit:**
Sorry, in the first version of answer I made error at rewriting your equations. Now are corrected.

Below are two version how you can draw your diagrams:

- with legend
- with label at above/below curves

```
\documentclass[margin=3mm, preview]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[height=44mm, width=88mm,
    grid=both,
    minor tick num=4,
    minor grid style = {very thin},
    ymax = 0.03, 
    xlabel = $x$,   ylabel = $y$,
    scaled y ticks=false,
    yticklabel style={/pgf/number format/.cd, fixed,  precision=2},
    tick label style = {font=\footnotesize},
    enlarge x limits = false,
    domain = 0:1,   samples = 201, no marks,
every axis plot post/.append style={very thick},
    legend style={cells={anchor=west, yshift=3mm}, 
                  font=\scriptsize,
                  legend pos = outer north east}
            ]
\addplot    {x/(70*(2-x^2))};
\addplot    {(1+sqrt(1-x^2))/70};
    \legend{$\frac{x}{70(2-x^2)}$, $\frac{1}{70(1+\sqrt{1-x^2})}$}
\end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
    
\bigskip
    \begin{tikzpicture}[
N/.style = {font= \footnotesize, text=black, pos=0.6}
                            ]
\begin{axis}[height=44mm, width=88mm,
    grid=both,
    minor tick num=4,
    minor grid style = {very thin},
    ymax = 0.03,
    xlabel = $x$,   ylabel = $y$,
    scaled y ticks=false,
    yticklabel style={/pgf/number format/.cd, fixed,  precision=2},
    tick label style = {font=\footnotesize},
    enlarge x limits = false,
    domain = 0:1,   samples = 201, no marks,
every axis plot post/.append style={very thick},
            ]
\addplot    {x/(70*(2-x^2))}        node[N, above] {$\frac{x}{70(2-x^2)}$};
\addplot    {(1+sqrt(1-x^2))/70}    node[N, below] {$\frac{1}{70(1+\sqrt{1-x^2})}$};
\end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you, how can label the graphs?

Comment: @MAHSA, labels now added.

Comment: I'm so sorry, why we have 2 zero?

Comment: @MAHSA, what you mean with zero? Blue curve atar at zero and as I select doman, finish with yero (I wrote my answer before you change the question, so I was guessing, what you after). You can change domain according to your wish.

Comment: please look at the picture that u uploaded, at left we have 2 zero

Comment: and I want the red curve domain to be 1.5 or more, but when I change it, just the blue curve is changed

Comment: ohhhh yes, because in my picture 2 curves cut each other but in your code doesn't. I'm so sorry but it very important for me

Comment: @MAHSA, upps, I made error ad rewriting your equation. See edited answer (two versions).